# Is the kernel flashed automatically from CWM?

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, fastboot, kernel, recovery-mode

By this, I mean, while flashing a firmware (update.zip) from ClockworkMod recovery, is boot.img also flashed or do I need to use fastboot separately?

Answer (score 3):

## What does the developer say?

Seriously every single rom that I've ever seen contained detailed instructions and more often than not a faq of some sorts for this reason exactly.

Anyway, if the zip file contains a `boot.img` file than it's safe to assume that it will be flashed. The `updater-script` that handles the copying of files is generated automatically when the rom is compiled so unless someone removes it, the kernel will be flashed.

Comment: I just checked the `updater-script` and it doesn’t seem to handle the kernel (no lines concerning `boot.img` or anything)

Comment: Hence the question at the top of the answer: `What does the developer say?` Did you just look at it or used grep/etc? In current rom it's `package_extract_file("boot.img", "tmp/boot.img");write_raw_image("/tmp/boot.img", "boot")`. The first part extract it, the second writes it to the `boot` partition.